# scipy.stats.gamma.fit

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

В библиотеке `scipy.stats` согласно документации распределение `gamma`  имеет только один параметр, но метод `scipy.stats.gamma.fit(data)` почему то возвращает кортеж из трех значений, а не одно! Почему так и какой из этих трëх является параметром, который затем можно подставить в функцию `scipy.stats.gamma.rvs` для генерации значений по подобранному закону распределения?

Answer (score 1):

А вы не пробовали самостоятельно прочитать документацию к тому методу, который используете?  Там же в самом начале текста указано *"The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form. To shift and/or scale the distribution use the **loc** and **scale parameters**"*.  Т.е. помимо стандартизованной формы распределения вы можете во-первых, сдвигать ваше распределение влево-вправо до оси `Х`, а также "растягивать" функцию плотности распределения по этой-же оси.

И соответственно при описании метода `gamma.fit()` тоже  рекомендуется ознакомиться c описанием `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit()` методом -  родителем. А уже там написано, *"Estimates for any shape parameters (if applicable), followed by those for **location** and **scale**. "* .

Вот вам и ваши три параметра, которые `fit` находит.